# indexing upper or lower triangle in matrix with diagonal

Tags: r, matrix

How can I index an upper or lower triangle matrix including the diagonal?

My matrix looks like this:

```
          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]     [,6]     [,7]      [,8]
[1,] 70.291456        NA       NA       NA        NA       NA       NA        NA
[2,] 47.059392 31.505769       NA       NA        NA       NA       NA        NA
[3,]  6.019712  4.030134 0.515524       NA        NA       NA       NA        NA
[4,]  2.993088  2.003841 0.256326 0.127449        NA       NA       NA        NA
```

what I have is this:

```
rows = 10    
cbind(row = unlist(lapply(2:rows, function(x) x:rows), use.names = FALSE), 
      col = rep(z[-length(z)], times = rev(tail(z, -1))-1))
```

the output for the above code looks like this:

```
     row col
[1,]   2   1
[2,]   3   1
[3,]   4   1
[4,]   5   1
[5,]   6   1
[6,]   7   1
[7,]   8   1
```

but this does not include the diagonal, which I've kept in my matrix (row 2 should match with [,1] and [,2] but it does not).

Comment: Have you tried the `?lower.tri` function?

Comment: And have you tried searching SO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the objective is to get the row and column numbers of the lower diagonal as well as the diagonal then if `m` is the input matrix then here are two solutions:

**1)**

```
ok <- lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE)
cbind(row = row(m)[ok], col = col(m)[ok])
```

**2)**

```
g <- expand.grid(row = 1:nrow(m), col = 1:ncol(m)) # grid
g[lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE), ]
```

**Added** Second solution.

Comment: `which(lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE), arr.ind=T)` would also work well.